# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable when using sum

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to obtain the sum of the return values obtained from the expenses_calc function, but I am facing "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". What changes do I need to make to solve this error?

```
from nsetools import Nse
    nse = Nse()

#Name of stocks and buy prices
stocks = {
    "APLAPOLLO": 878.2,
    "AVANTIFEED": 488.95,
    "BALAMINES": 308.95
}

#Quantity of stocks
qty = {
    "APLAPOLLO": 10,
    "AVANTIFEED": 10,
    "BALAMINES": 10
}

def get_closing(stock):
    """
    Function to obtain closePrice of stocks
    """
    return nse.get_quote(stock)['buyPrice1']

def expenses_calc(buy,sell,qty):
    """
    Function to calculate the applicable expenses
    """
    stt = 0.10
    ttc = 0.00325
    service_tax = 15.0
    sebi_charges = 0.0002
    swacch_bharat_cess = 0.02
    stamp_duty = 0.01

    turnover = (buy * qty) + (sell * qty)
    stt_total = (stt / 100) * turnover
    total_tran_charge = (ttc / 100) * turnover
    service_tax = (service_tax / 100) * total_tran_charge
    sebi_charges = (sebi_charges / 100) * turnover
    stamp_duty = (stamp_duty / 100) * turnover
    total_tax_and_charges = stt_total + total_tran_charge + service_tax + sebi_charges + stamp_duty
    total_investment = buy * qty
    current_value = sell * qty
    net_profit = (sell * qty) - (buy * qty) - total_tax_and_charges
    return net_profit

#For loop that calls the expenses_calc function in a loop with the right arguments
for key in stocks.keys():
    buy_price = stocks[key]
    sell_price = get_closing(key)
    stock_qty = qty[key]
    expenses_func_call = expenses_calc(buy_price, sell_price, stock_qty)
    print(sum(expenses_func_call))
```

The line where the type error occurs

```
print(sum(expenses_func_call))
```

I have tried creating an empty myresults list and then appending the return value of expenses_calc function to it then printing the sum of the list, which also doesn't work.

```
for key in stocks.keys():
    myresults = []
    buy_price = stocks[key]
    sell_price = get_closing(key)
    stock_qty = qty[key]
    expenses_func_call = expenses_calc(buy_price, sell_price, stock_qty)
    myresults.append(expenses_func_call)
    print(sum(myresults))
```

Comment: `sum` expects an iterable, `expenses_func_call` is the result of a call to `expenses_calc`, and `expenses_calc` returns a number, not an iterable.

Comment: And did you try initializing `myresults = []` before the loop, rather than on every iteration? And in what way did it not work - an error message? Wrong output? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the previous answer, you need to pass a list to the `sum` function, so your initial attempt to correct the problem is correct. But you should initialize the `myresults` list before entering the loop. Currently, each time you execute the loop, you are in effect overwriting the `myresults` content.

Answer (score 0):

In your next attempt with appending values to the list myresults, your print statement should be outside the for loop

Comment: I tried that, it just prints the return value of the last key without making using of sum at all